# Show that whole number inputs to a in $x = a \left(2+\frac23\right)$ will result in an answer divisible by $3$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the formula $x = a \left(2+\frac23\right)$.  The series progresses like this:

```
1: 2.666667
2: 5.333333
3: 8
4: 10.66667
5: 13.33333
6: 16
...
...
89: 237.3333
90: 240
```

It is clear to see that whole number answers to the formula arise from inputs in [a] that are divisible by $3$, and I wondered how I should have been able to infer that relationship from the formula itself.  And I thought it would turn out to be obvious, but unfortunately, I am *not* finding that the relationship is immediately obvious.  So I thought I would ask the question, expose my ignorance, and hopefully learn something.

Comment: Is $8$ divisible by $3?$

Comment: @Vanessa no, 8 is not divisible by 3.  But then 8 does not provide a whole number answer to the question either.

Comment: What do you mean by **whole number answer**....8 is a whole number

Comment: @Vanessa I mean that the answer to the question is an integer.  As shown in the series.

Comment: 8 is an integer...dude

Comment: @Vanessa Fortunately I am not that stupid.  However, I do now understand the confusion and it stems from the way I've worded the question.  But... I didn't come here to be made to look stupid either so I suppose I will simply not ask the question at all.

Comment: If you worded the question incorrectly then just edit it :\

Comment: @Q'' I would encourage you to edit your questions in response to comments rather than giving up on it. Comments are there to help you improve the question so it can attract higher quality answers and be more easily searched. It's not a personal attack, it's just meant to help you clarify what you mean. Math is a social discipline and we work together to ensure everything makes sense. If you want to get good at math, you'll need to get good at hearing criticism. Even the best mathematicians need it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you - you are of course 100% correct.

Comment: $x= a(2+\frac{2}{3})$ $x=a\frac{8}{3}$ " If $a$ is a multiply of $3$ say $a=3b$ " $x=3b\cdot\frac{8}{3}$ $x=8b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $a$-th term of your series is given by $ \frac{8a}{3}$, where $a \in \mathbb{N}$ (since $2 + \frac23 = \frac83$). Notice that a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ is an integer if and only if $q$ divides $p$, so your question is equivalent to asking when $3 $ divides $8a$. Since $3$ is prime, if it divides a product then it must divide one of the factors:
$$
3 \vert 8a \implies 3 \vert8 \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ 3\vert a
$$
but since $3$ doesn't divide $8$, the only possibilty is that $3$ divides $a$.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't understand "where a∈N" but fortunately a quick google of that pointed me to the nomenclature of set symbols.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=a\cdot\left(2+\frac 23\right)$$
$$x=\frac{8a}{3}$$ $\implies$ that $x$ will be an integer when $a$ is divisible by $3$ or $a=3k$ for some integral $k$